# Error al leer campo Double de Base de Datos Mysql

Tags: vb.net, .net

Hola me trae de los pelos esto y seguramente es una pavada pero que complejo me resulta comprender como maneja los tipos de datos .NET 
El Tema es que tengo en una Base de DAtos Mysql un campo definido como DOUBLE y que un registro determinado tiene un valor **3000.00** y al leerlo desde mi código y cargarlo en una variable definida como DOUBLE también me devuelve **3000** redondo sin los decimales.
Esto sucede siempre que los decimales son .00  por que si el valor en la Base de Datos fuera **3000.25** el comportamiento es correcto y obtengo en la variable TmpRemu = 3000.25

QUE ESTOY HACIENDO MAL?

```
    If Operaciones.Buscar("SELECT *  FROM t_empleados " &
                          "WHERE id_user=" & user_id & " " &
                          "And f_empleador =" & empresa_id & " And activo=1") = True Then

        DataGridEmpleado.DataSource = Acceso.ds.Tables(0)

    Else
        DataGridEmpleado.DataSource = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim TmpRemu As Double
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To DataGridEmpleado.RowCount - 1
       'ACA OBTENGO EL VALOR DEL CAMPO REMUNECACION
        TmpRemu = CDbl(DataGridEmpleado.Rows(i).Cells("f_remuneracion").Value)
    Next
```

Comment: Para un tipo decimal lo mismo es 3000.00 que 3000, no deberia afectarte en nada. ¿O es que utilizas ese dato luego para mostrarlo en algún sitio? Si es así al convertirlo a string puedes formatearlo para que siempre muestre dos decimales.

Comment: Hola, sí tengo que seguir con el proceso del código y necesito siempre tener el formato con 2 decimales. Quiero tratar el problema no disfrazarlo por que puedo formatearlo como dices pero no creo sea la solucion correcta. Gracias

Comment: Es lo que me refiero, mientras estés operando con la variable TmpRemu, que es tipo double, no afectan en nada los decimales puesto que es lo mismo. ¿Que más operaciones haces con la variable para que te afecten los decimales?